# Learning Iterators (Dive into Python3)

Tags: python, iterator

A question is based on [this snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34713524/iterator-example-from-dive-into-python-3) The author's comments on this are following:

> This read-build-and-cache process will continue as long as the rules being read from the pattern file don’t match the word we’re trying to pluralize. If we do find a matching rule before the end of the file, we simply use it and stop, with the file still open. The file pointer will stay wherever we stopped reading, waiting for the next readline() command. In the meantime, the cache now has more items in it, and if we start all over again trying to pluralize a new word, **each of those items in the cache** will be tried before reading the next line from the pattern file.

1. I do not see any implementation of that is in bold in the quoted text above. How exactly each of cached item is tried?
2. Is it correct that self.cache is cleared on every object call?

Answer (score 0):

1. It's in the `plural` function:

```
for matches_rule, apply_rule in rules:
    if matches_rule(noun):
```

2. Every new instance of the `LazyRules` class (e.g. `rules = LazyRules()`)  starts with its own empty cache (`self.cache = []` under `__init__`). Every time you iterate over that object (`for ... in rules`) after the first time it can use that cache.